# Send Data from HTML to Python

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, python-2.7

I have an HTML page, and I want to use the Data in the Username field in a code in python. What methods should I use. I am not using any python framework.

```
    <body>
    <div id="Header" >
        </div>
   <div id="wrapper">

        <form name="login-form" class="login-form" action="" method="post"  onsubmit=    "validate();return false;">

        <div class="header">
        <h1>Login Form</h1>

        </div>

        <div class="content">
        <input id="Uname" name="username" type="text" class="input username" placeholder="Username" />
        <div class="user-icon"></div>
        <input id="Pname"name="password" type="password" class="input password" placeholder="Password" />
        <div class="pass-icon"></div>       
        </div>

        <div class="footer">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" class="button"/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" class="register" />
        </div>

    </form>
       </div>

<div class="gradient"></div>
</body>
```

Validate() is a javascript function used to validate the credentials.

Comment: Are you using a web server? What type of web server are you using?

Comment: That's not really any better. What exactly would it mean to "send the data" to a Python script? Where is that script going to run? Especially as this appears to be a login page, so you will need to set the user's session cookie etc and use it in the rest of the site - but you haven't described how that site is being served or what it has to do with the Python script.

Comment: I am not using a web server. I need to get that string over to that python script where I can authenticate it and then send .json data back to the page.

Comment: "*I am not using a web server*" - Okay -- where are you storing that HTML file and how are you invoking it?

Comment: I am invoking it using _firefox test.html_ command

Answer (score -1):

in your HTML form,

```
action="yourpythonfile.py"
```

and in your python file,

```
import cgi
frm = cgi.FieldStorage()
print frm.getvalue('username')
```